# How to remove this JSON prefix ")]}',\n" in the Angular to deal with JSON vulnerabilities

Tags: angular

Our Webservice JSON output is implemented to protect JSON vulnerabilities. Hence the JSON start with this prefix ")]}',"

I have gone through few articles and came to know that HttpClient provides some libraries to strip this JSON prefix however I'm not able to get the proper example of it.

Need help to understand how to implement this.

Sample JSON

```
)]}',
[{
    "Product": "Business Cards",
    "Description": "Business Card description"
}, {
    "Product": "Flyers",
    "Description": "Flyers description"
}]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
httpClient.get(..., {responseType: 'text'}.pipe(
  map(value => //remove chars),
  map(transformed =>  JSON.parse(transformed));
```

propably You'll be have to use `{responseType: 'text' as 'json'}` to avoid errors on compile

Comment: There is no special class available to remove this string. Or we just need to use regular string classes to strip off this string like substr etc.

Comment: custom method I think